# FreeRADIUS authentication using Active Directory

Tags: centos, active-directory, radius, freeradius

I am trying to implement RADIUS authentication using Active Directory. I want requests to RADIUS to be sent to AD server and RADIUS responds according to its result.

I've already joined RADIUS server to domain, so I can do 
`ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=MYDOMAIN --username=user --password=password`
 and it works.

Now I am trying to make FreeRADIUS use `ntlm_auth` according to [this](http://wemakeitsimple.blogspot.com/2013/02/configuring-freeradius-authentication.html) manual, but after adding

```
DEFAULT     Auth-Type = ntlm_auth
```

to `users` file `radiusd` doesn't start. Without it `radiusd` starts but doesn't authenticate using AD.

Error when `radiusd` not starting:

```
/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[1]: Parse error (check) for entry DEFAULT: Unknown value 'ntlm_auth' for attribute 'Auth-Type'
Failed reading /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
```

I am using FreeRADIUS 3.0.4, CentOS 7.2

How to make FreeRADIUS to proxy authentication requests to Active Directory?

Comment: Are you unaware that Windows includes its own RADIUS server?

Comment: Now I am aware and will try this way. But is the way I described impossible?

Comment: It might be possible. But it will certainly be much easier to use Windows NPS, especially if most of the users are using Windows.